# JOOQ : Unable to implement Seek in Dynamic Query

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I am trying to write a Dynamic query which uses the `seek` method. My usage of `addSeekAfter` as a replacement for `seek` is flawed. How do I fix it?

```
// my current setup
create.select(TOPIC.ID, TOPIC.DESCRIPTION)
.from(TOPIC)
.orderBy(TOPIC.MODIFIED_ON.desc(), TOPIC.ID.desc())
.seek(recModifiedOn, ULong.valueOf(recentTopicId))
.limit(noOfRecords)
.fetch()
.map(new TopicRecordMapper());

// what I want to move to
SelectQuery query = create.selectQuery();
query.addSelect(TOPIC.ID, TOPIC.DESCRIPTION);
query.addFrom(TOPIC);
query.addOrderBy(TOPIC.MODIFIED_ON.desc(), TOPIC.ID.desc());
// below addSeekAfter is not yielding identical results as above
query.addSeekAfter(
 DSL.field(TOPIC.MODIFIED_ON.le(TimeUtils.getTime(recentModifiedOn))),  
 DSL.field(TOPIC.ID.le(ULong.valueOf(recentTopicId))));
query.addLimit(noOfRecords);
query.fetch().map(new TopicRecordMapper());
```

Answer (score 3):

The DSL API provides a convenience method [`seek(T1, T2)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/SelectSeekStep2.html#seek-T1-T2-) where this:

```
.seek(value1, value2)
```

Is just short for this:

```
.seek(DSL.val(value1), DSL.val(value2))
```

In fact, most of jOOQ's API is overloaded for convenience so that you don't have to explicitly create bind values using [`DSL.val()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#val-T-) all the time.

However, the "model API" ([see the manual's section about DSL vs model API for details](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/dsl-and-non-dsl/)) doesn't contain as many convenience methods. Which means that you have to create bind values explicitly. Write this:

```
query.addSeekAfter(
    DSL.val(recentModifiedOn),  
    DSL.val(ULong.valueOf(recentTopicId)));
```

[For more information, please consider also looking into the manual's section about bind variables](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/).

Comment: Thanks a lot Lukas. JOOQ is just a great implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to solve it. Is it the right way?

```
Field[] topicIdArgs = new Field[]{DSL.val(ULong.valueOf(recentTopicId), ULong.class)};
Field[] args = new Field[]{DSL.val(TimeUtils.getTime(recentModifiedOn), Timestamp.class)};
query.addSeekAfter(DSL.function("", Timestamp.class, args), DSL.function("", ULong.class, topicIdArgs));
```

[Edited. Look at Lukas' answer below]

Comment: While that will work, it is certainly not necessary to do this way. Wrapping your bind values in pseudo-functions seems a bit like overkill. With jOOQ, there's usually an easier way :)